# Laravel multiple data query

Tags: laravel

the db contains a list of users with the dateSTART and dateSTOP fields.
With the query I should get the records relating to a specific user for the current month, considering valid even if only one of the two date fields (START or STOP) contains the current month.
Considering that the start and stop values could be around the current month, the query should consider an OR.
I tried as described below, but I get an error in the function, related to the lastname and name parameters passed as $request.

```
public function listOfMonth(Request $request){
    $lastname=$request->get('lastname');
    $name=$request->get('name');
    $result=DB::table('timbraturas')
            ->where('lastname',$lastname)
            ->where('name',$name)
            ->whereMonth('dateSTART','=',Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereYear('dateSTART','=',Carbon::now()->year)
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
                $query->where('lastname',$lastname)
                ->where('name',$name)
                ->whereYear('dateSTOP','=',Carbon::now()->year)
                ->whereMonth('dataSTOP','=',Carbon::now()->month);
            })   
            ->orderBy('id','asc')
            ->get();
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass variables to Clousure, you have to use `use` keyword like this:

```php
public function listOfMonth(Request $request) {
    $lastname=$request->get('lastname');
    $name=$request->get('name');
    $result=DB::table('timbraturas')
            ->where('lastname', $lastname)
            ->where('name', $name)
            ->whereMonth('dateSTART', '=', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->whereYear('dateSTART', '=', Carbon::now()->year)
            ->orWhere(function($query) use ($lastname, $name) {
                $query->where('lastname', $lastname)
                ->where('name', $name)
                ->whereYear('dateSTOP', '=', Carbon::now()->year)
                ->whereMonth('dataSTOP', '=', Carbon::now()->month);
            })   
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
            ->get();
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling nested functions like that you need to pass variables in if they are defined in the outer scope with `use` like this:

```
function($query) use ($name,  $lastname) {
```